# PostgreSQL - Self updating serial field

Tags: postgresql, sorting, auto-increment

I got a table with 3 fields, `seq` of type `integer` and `tstamp` of type `timestamp` and `txt` of type `text`.
Example:

```
seq | tstamp              | txt
--------------------------------
1   | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 | A
2   | 2014-01-02 00:00:00 | B 
3   | 2014-01-03 00:00:00 | C
```

**What i want to do:**

If an insert of the following row timestamp -> `2014-01-02 12:00:00` occours, i would like to get my seq field updated according to the ordered tstamp

**Result i want:**

```
seq | tstamp              | txt
--------------------------------
1   | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 | A 
2   | 2014-01-02 00:00:00 | B
3   | 2014-01-02 12:00:00 | A
4   | 2014-01-03 00:00:00 | C
```

I know i can trap an insert trigger and update the seq field following the tstamp order but it looks very inefficient for million insert made every day.

There's a better way to do this? Like... some kind of self-updating serial type i'm not aware of...

**Why i need this?**

I need an always-updated sequence field because i would like to know, if I search only record with txt field set to A, if there's a time "hole" between them or they are sequentially close in the no-filtered table

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE txt = 'A';
```

*Result:*

```
seq | tstamp              | txt
--------------------------------
1   | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 | A 
3   | 2014-01-02 12:00:00 | A
```

The application receving result of the query just have to check seq against previous seq (`current seq != previous seq + 1`) to detect a "hole" between results. That's why the only tstamp is not enough

Comment: Are you up to [serial type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) here?

Comment: *There's a better way to do this?* If `seq`'s only role is to provide a numeric ordering based on `tstamp`: just drop it (it's redundant). You can safely order your queries based on `tstamp` or calculate `seq`'s value in each query itself. If `seq`'s role also to provide a primary key: it's the worst approach change it.

Comment: @pozs: the timestamp value is not necessarily unique on a busy system and thus the numbering might not be consistent upon retrieval

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah, that's why I wrote *if*. Another *if* could be the consistent ordering, but that could be achieved with a secondary field (which only gets updates, if two or more timestamps are really equals) more easily & painlessly.

Comment: I updated the post with a better explaining of my problem... sorry i was a not clear on the first hand

Comment: @pozs Er, "a secondary field which only gets update[d] if two or more timestamps are equal" is certainly *not* the simplest way. It's way less efficient and is unnecessarily complicated. It can be both reasonable and appropriate to use both a synthetic key and a timestamp.

Comment: @CraigRinger yeah, you're right. Than a simple sequence can handle that with `ORDER BY tstamp, id` -- but constantly updating a sequence-like field is definitely not the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need a numeric ordering to achieve your goal: you can detect holes with `lag()` & `lead()` [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    not (txt = (lag(txt) over (order by tstamp))) as hole_before,
    not (txt = (lead(txt) over (order by tstamp))) as hole_after
  from t
) t
where txt = 'B';
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8833b/6)

**EDIT**: if your data can hold multiple equal `tstamp` value (note that by default, there is no explicit bound on precision of a timestamp field), and you want to get a constant order over them, add a `serial` to your table & use `order by tstamp, id` in your window functions. Without it, queries over your table could return with inconsistently each time, f.ex:

```
   First query's result could be        Second query's result could be

      2014-01-03 00:00:00 | A             2014-01-03 00:00:00 | B
      2014-01-03 00:00:00 | B             2014-01-03 00:00:00 | A
```

Comment: That's exactly the answer i expected! A function i didn't know that already does what i need! Thank you very much!